# How to convert const to non const

Tags: c++, data-structures

I've been given the following functions to write

```
T getMinimum() const {}
```

and I have to use the following helper function

```
void getMinimumHelper(Node * subtree, Node * &Location) const {}
```

However, I've never known how to pass a function like this. I have a binary search tree class with a node as a member of the BST class. I've tried a lot of things such as

```
Node * minNode = this->Node;
Node minNode = this->getMinimumHelper(findMin, findMin);
return minNode->data;
```

Helper function:

```
void getMinimumHelper(Node * subtree, Node * &Location) const {
    if (subtree == NULL){
        Location = NULL;
    }
    if (subtree->left == NULL){
        Location = subtree;
    }
    else{
        getMinimumHelper(subtreeRoot->left, subtree);
    }
}
```

however I get illegal as right side of '->'
and of course the helper function is void for whatever reason so it doesn't actually return anything. I've been working on this for hours and haven't made any headway at all and cannot figure this out. And I have many more functions with helper functions like this and I have no idea what to do.

Class:

```
template <class T>
class  {
private:
    class Node {
    public:
        T data;
        Node * left;
        Node * right;
        Node * parent;

        Node() :left(NULL), right(NULL), parent(NULL) {};
        Node(const T& item) {
            data = item;
            left = NULL;
            right = NULL;
            parent = NULL;
        };
    };
public:
    BST();
    BST(BST&);

    ~BST();

    bool isEmpty() const;
    bool search(const T&) const;
private:
    Node * _root;

    void getMaximumHelper(Node *, Node * &) const;
    void getMinimumHelper(Node *, Node * &) const;
};
```

Comment: What is your problem? You have to write the getMinimum() ?

Comment: I guess, That parameter Node * &minLocation parameter in getMinimumHelper() is where you will get the Node* where min value is found. Pass the sub-tree Node* as first param where you want to find out the min value in and get the Node* in return where min value is, I guess that's how that helper function is devised.

Node * minNode = new Node();
this->getMinimumHelper(this->Node, minNode);
return minNode->data;

Comment: Yes I understand that's what I have to do, my problem is passing the parameters into getMinimumHelper(), I know this is a BST and therefore the leftmost node should be the minimum value, however because getMinimum() is const I cannot use that value (simply tried a this pointer, this->node)in my getMinimumHelper function, and I cannot figure out a way to change it so I can.

Comment: Also, the helper function being void doesn't help me at all. I don't have a minimum data member to simply return so it makes everything a lot harder than it has to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
template <class T>
T BinarySearchTree<T>::getMinimum() const {
    Node * minNode;
    getMinimumHelper(_root, minNode);
    return minNode->data;
};
```

Comment: Assuming that - since it has a reference to the node pointer - `getMinimumHelper()` modifies its second parameter in-place, you are laking memory. The `new Node()` thing is superfluous.

Comment: Right, We really don't know how getMinimumHelper() is implemented! This is just quick workout.

Comment: @user3376703, Can you post getMinimumHelper()?

Comment: Just an FYI this is my implementation. It was not written already.

 if (subtreeRoot == NULL){
  minLocation = NULL;
 }
 if (subtreeRoot->left == NULL){
   minLocation = subtreeRoot;
 }
 else{
  getMinimumHelper(subtreeRoot->left, subtreeRoot);
 }

Comment: `Node * findMin = new Node();
 getMinimumHelper(this->Node, findMin);
 return findMin->data;`

this->Node gives the following error:'function-style cast' : illegal as right side of '->' operator

Comment: @user3376703, so you want to find out a node in it's sub-tree which has the minimum value, Correct? You need to provide that Node* as first param when calling getMinimumHelper(). 

Suppose, I want to find out min value in sub-tree of _root.

template <class T>
T BinarySearchTree<T>::getMinimum() const {
 Node * minNode = new Node();
 getMinimumHelper(_root, minNode);
 return minNode->data;
};

By the way, you haven't provided the helper function yet.

Comment: I did in these comments, but I can't figure out how to use code blocks properly in comments, I edited the question to make it easier to find.

Comment: okay, I missed that. Anyway, then you need not worry about that "new".

template <class T>
T BinarySearchTree<T>::getMinimum() const {
 Node * minNode;
 getMinimumHelper(_root, minNode);
 return minNode->data;
};

Comment: I did that, however getMinimumHelper(this->Node, findMin); gives me an error because of this->node

'function-style cast' : illegal as right side of '->' operator

Comment: I feel really dumb for never noticing _root... This happens a lot to me. Thanks for the help man, I should be able to do the rest of this now that I understand what I did wrong. I really appreciate everyone's help.